# Shell script not reading getopts arguments on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have written a script that performs tasks according to switches used on command line. Here is my script:
Expects the git branch name and two optional switches

-r for resetting database

-t for merging training data

**test.sh**

```
merge_training=false
reset_database=false

while getopts ":tr" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    t ) # process option t
       echo "one"
       $merge_training=true
       ;;
    r ) # process option r
       echo "two"
       $reset_database=true
       ;;
   esac
done

echo $reset_database
echo $merge_training
```

When I run this script with command:

```
sh test.sh branchname -r -t
```

It does not print **one** or **two** and the last statements prints:

```
false
false
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try run without sh. Just ./test.sh branchname -r -t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is your assignments.  Your should have got 2 error messages saying:

```
false=true: command not found
```

Hint:  Never put a `$` on the left-side of an assignment:

The convention is to put options *first*, then extra parameters, so your command-line should be:

```
bash test.sh -r -t branchname
```

Use `bash` not `sh`.  `sh` is a POSIX shell and is roughly a subset of `bash` (its complicated).  Don't confuse the two.

```
merge_training=false
reset_database=false

while getopts ":tr" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    t ) # process option t
       echo "one"
       merge_training=true     #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       ;;
    r ) # process option r
       echo "two"
       reset_database=true     #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       ;;
   esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND-1 ))
extra="$1"

echo $reset_database
echo $merge_training
echo $extra
```

Comment: Not alone that, the `OPTSTRING` processing is wrong, needs a `shift 1`

Comment: Thanks cdarke, spot on

Answer (score 2):

when you remove the `branchname` as a param, then it works (- but you have to also remove the `$` from `$merge_training=true`, else you try to `false=true`..)

So what you could do is to save the `$1` param in a variable and simply shift.

Here the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

merge_training=false
reset_database=false
branchname="$1"
shift
while getopts ":tr" opt; do
  case $opt in
    t ) # process option t
       echo "one"
       merge_training=true
       ;;
    r ) # process option r
       echo "two"
       reset_database=true
       ;;
   esac
done

echo $branchname
echo $reset_database
echo $merge_training
```

Comment: We literally have the same answer ;)

Comment: and I literally thought just the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the points you could enhance on your script,

1. Variable assignments don't take `$` on the left-hand-side
2. The command-line arguments are seeing an extra argument `branchname` before processing the actual `OPTSTRING`, you need to *exclude* the first parameter before getting into the `getopts()` call.
3. Always set the shell interpreter to the one you want to run your script with. In `bash` do `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
4. Always quote your shell variables unless you have a good reason not to.

The updated script should look like below if you are passing arguments as `bash test.sh branchname -r -t`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

merge_training=false
reset_database=false

branchname="$1"
shift 1

while getopts ":tr" opt; do
  case "${opt}" in
    t ) # process option t
       echo "one"
       merge_training=true
       ;;
    r ) # process option r
       echo "two"
       reset_database=true
       ;;
   esac
done

echo "$reset_database"
echo "$merge_training"
```